# Is there something wrong with nested ArrayList Initialization?

Tags: java, generics, collections, bounded-wildcard

Consider these following classes:

```
class A{ }
class B extends A{ }
```

As we know this compiles fine:

```
List<? extends A> xx = new ArrayList<B>();
List<? extends List<? extends A>> xy = new ArrayList<List<? extends A>>();
```

But this gives compile time error

```
List<? extends A> yx = new ArrayList<? extends A>();
List<? extends List<? extends A>> yy = new ArrayList<? extends List<? extends A>>();
```

The error says:

> required: class or interface without bounds

I'm aware that the fresh values interpreted by the compiler for the above initializations are different, and thus they cannot be cast safely.
But what does 'without bounds' means in the above error message?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not using `<>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner, I just want to understand what the error message wants to say in simple words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is referring to the creation of the new `ArrayList` whose direct, top-level type parameter is using a wildcard.  This is not allowed, despite the fact that a *nested* type parameter is allowed to have a wildcard.

The [JLS, Section 15.9, "Class Instance Creation Expressions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), states:

> If *TypeArguments* is present immediately after `new`, or immediately before `(`, then it is a compile-time error if any of the type arguments are wildcards ([§4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)).

The key word here is "immediately", because that represents the direct type argument, not the nested type argument.

Here is the restriction mentioned in [Angelika Langer's article about generics and its usages](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaPro/02.JavaGenericsWildcards/Wildcards.html#More%20Details%20Regarding%20the%20Wildcard%20Language%20Feature):

> They [wildcards] can not be used for creation of objects or arrays, that is, a wildcard instantiation is not permitted in a new expression.  Wildcard instantiations are not types, they are **placeholders for a member from a family of types**.  In a way, a wildcard instantiation is similar to an interface:  we can declare variables of interface types, but we cannot create objects of interface types; the created objects must be of a class type that implements the interface.  Similar with wildcard instantiations: we can declare variables of a wildcard instantiated type, but we cannot create objects of such a type; the created objects must be of a concrete instantiation from the family of instantiations designated by the wildcard instantiation.

(emphasis mine)

Basically, a wildcard type is not a concrete type and cannot be instantiated, with similar reasoning to not being allowed to create an instance of interface directly.

However, that says nothing about nested wildcards, which relate to the creation of initially unrelated objects that may eventually be associated with this type.  In  your example, this would be the nested `List`s that may be added to the outer `ArrayList`.  They could be references to `List`s of any matching wildcard type, but they're not being created here.

**Summary**

Java doesn't allow a wildcard in a instance creation expression (with `new`), but it does allow a nested wildcard in such an expression, because a direct wildcard type is not a concrete type.

Answer (score 2):

The type arguments to the class instance being created can't be wildcards ([§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)):

> If [type arguments are] present immediately after `new`, or immediately before `(`, then it is a compile-time error if any of the type arguments are wildcards.

That's pretty much it. The type arguments may contain wildcards (as in `new ArrayList<List<?>>`), but wildcards can't be given directly (as in `new ArrayList<?>`).

This distinction is maybe clarified by the grammar of type arguments which the above quote references ([§4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)):

```
TypeArguments:
    < TypeArgumentList >

TypeArgumentList:
    TypeArgument {, TypeArgument}

TypeArgument:
    ReferenceType
    Wildcard

Wildcard:
    {Annotation} ? [WildcardBounds]

WildcardBounds:
    extends ReferenceType
    super ReferenceType
```

In other words, for each `TypeArgument` in the `TypeArgumentList` provided to the class instance creation expression, the `TypeArgument` may only be a `ReferenceType` and not a `Wildcard`. If a reference type is *itself* generic, then it *can* have type arguments provided to *it* which are wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of construction / defenition of a generic type the type has to be specified. Both of these

```
? extends A
? extends List<? exetnds A>
```

are creating a new wildcard which is an yet unknown generic type (you can tell from the ? in front).

Both of these

```
B
List<? extends A>
```

are actual types. So when calling

```
new ArrayList<B>();
new ArrayList<List<? extends A>>();
```

The generic type is specified. In once case it is `B`, in the other it is a `List` containing `? extends A`.

When calling

new ArrayList();
new ArrayList>();

Both times the generic type is undefined. This is not allowed.

The reason why `List<? extends A>` doesn't cause the error is, because here it is a type. The List within your original `List<? extends List<? extends A>>` wasn't created yet. You only define that later it has to be a `List<? extends A>`. If you would try to create this list like this

```
new ArrayList<? extends A>();
```

You will run into the same problem.

Understandable?